# Não há linha entre respostas. Isso é um bug ou é by-design?

Tags: bug, status-intencional, design, layout

No Stack Overflow quando uma pergunta tem 2 ou mais respostas elas são separadas por uma linha. No Stack Overflow Português esta linha não está aparecendo.

[image: Linha entre respostas]

Isto é algum bug?

<sub>Eu particularmente prefiro com a linha.</sub>

Comment: Não acho que seja um bug... pode ser uma alteração no layout.

Comment: Eu acho que seria mais importante separar a pergunta da primeira resposta com a linha do que as respostas entre si.

Comment: Se for bug, adianto que prefiro sem a linha, fica mais *clean*.

Comment: Nosso layout é diferente do SOen. E sem a linha.